# Explorer View on Front end Server won't open

Tags: explorer-view

I'm trying to navigate some Explorer views in a front end server (
SharePoint 2013 on premises)
The user I'm logged in the server is site collection administrator.

When I open a library in Explorer view from the ribbon I get:

> We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add
>   this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again

The site is in my trusted sites.

Can I open a sharepoint library in Explorer view on a sharepoint server?
Or there is some sort of protection that prevents me from doing so. And if that is the case, could I bypass it or disable somehow?

Comment: some of the usual problems are not having Desktop Experience,  loopback check, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of steps to get this working:

1. Add the desktop experience to the server using Server Manager (or PowerShell).
2. Ensure the WebClient Windows Service is running.